# filtering unnecessary data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to download a table from this site.

[What caused the table to download incorrectly was a link embedded in the team names and a second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK4So.png)

My main goal is to get the entire table. but I can't do this because of the secondary tables embedded in the team names. How can I get the entire table on this page as an Excel spreadsheet?

this is my code 1

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl as op

url = 'https://footystats.org/england/premier-league/form-table'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

data1 = pd.read_html(StringIO(r.text), skiprows=0, header=0)[41]
print(data1)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data1.to_excel(writer)
writer._save()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYNvk.png)

this is my code 2

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import xlsxwriter
url = 'https://footystats.org/england/premier-league/form-table'
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

dfs = pd.read_html(StringIO(r.text))
am=len(dfs)
df =dfs[41]
print(df)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer)

writer._save()
```

[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXCtN.png)

Comment: Do note: as of pandas v2.1, [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) supports `storage_options` where you can directly pass your header dict, avoiding use of `requests`.

Comment: Looking at source, the webpage is mostly Javascript rendered. `read_html` will only retrieve static tables on page (i.e., viewable in source). Consider other solutions to retrieve such dynamic content like selenium to pass response into `read_html`.

Comment: The question should include a representative sample of the input data; it becomes completely useless once the site goes away or changes its format in the slightest.

Comment: Do you think I should use selenium?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your approach and parse the data using BeautifulSoup before using it to create a Pandas DataFrame.

```py
url = "https://footystats.org/england/premier-league/form-table"
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
tds = soup.find_all("td", class_="team")

teams = []
for td in tds:
    team_name = td.find("a").find("h3").text.strip()
    teams.append(team_name)

# Remove duplicates
teams = list(set(teams))

df = pd.DataFrame({"Teams": teams})

print(df)
```

This will result in:

```
                         Teams
0                Luton Town FC
1            Crystal Palace FC
2    Brighton & Hove Albion FC
3                   Burnley FC
4                    Fulham FC
5           West Ham United FC
6                 Liverpool FC
7          Sheffield United FC
8           Manchester City FC
9                   Chelsea FC
10                  Arsenal FC
11                  Everton FC
12  Wolverhampton Wanderers FC
13              Aston Villa FC
14                Brentford FC
15        Nottingham Forest FC
16             AFC Bournemouth
17         Newcastle United FC
18        Tottenham Hotspur FC
19        Manchester United FC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I want to get the whole table. Subtables embedded in team names were preventing me from retrieving the entire table. Currently there are only team names, how can I get the entire table in tabular form?